# Theano installation:Error:error: '::hypot' has not been declared using ::hypot;

Tags: theano

I cloned theano from Git and just ran from the directory python setup.py install.
But I am  getting the following error.
'error: '::hypot' has not been declared
   using ::hypot;'
I am using windows 8.1 with Python 3.5.
Please  anybody help.

Comment: duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42276984/hypot-has-not-been-declared

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['::hypot' has not been declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42276984/hypot-has-not-been-declared)