# '::hypot' has not been declared

Tags: python, c++, machine-learning, theano

I'm using python3.6 theano, 
with mingw-w64-x86-64 installed, my os is Win10_64, cuda installed, 
and seems everything is ok

the theano.test() is ok, saying my gpu is working,

but it just keeps tell me that "error: '::hypot' has not been declared"

```
 C:/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/cmath:1157:11: error: '::hypot' has 
 not been declared\r.    using ::hypot;\r.            ^~~~~\r. ",
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you botched your compiler setup.

Answer (score 16):

I had this error with building an python file using mingw32 .
I opened the file that it says (C:/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/cmath:1157:11)
and changed that line to

```
using ::_hypot;
```

or adding this line just before that :

```
#define hypot _hypot
```

and after that the problem was solved !!
I know it's not a basic solution but it is the one that I could find !!

Comment: Oh, yes! It works for ...\mingw-w64\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\8.1.0\include\c++\cmath : 1121

Comment: https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/4926 also advises to add THEANO_FLAGS='gcc.cxxflags="-D_hypot=hypot"' to the environment variables.

Comment: I had to keep the original mingw cmath header (otherwise libpng would not build) and I commented out the #define hypot _hypot in pyconfig.h (line 241). Worked for me.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend against editing system header files as it will just munt things up for any other times you use the compiler for other projects, and could lead to a "butterfly effect" of weird consequences .

Answer (score 2):

(This answer was posted in comments originally)

> I had to keep the original mingw cmath header (otherwise libpng would not build) and I commented out the `#define hypot _hypot` in `pyconfig.h` (line 241).

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to use the combination of the answers above:

```
#ifdef _WIN64
#define _hypot hypot
#include <cmath>
#endif
#include <pybind11.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess from your incomplete information is that you aren't compiling in C++11 mode so you aren't picking up `::hypot` from C99.