# How to build GDB on Windows

Tags: windows, debugging, build, gdb, toolchain

How does one build GDB (the GNU Debugger) from source on Windows?  I need to build it in order to make a build with Python support.  I cannot use the one distributed with Cygwin because it has problems interpreting backslashes on Windows.  What toolchains do I need for the build -- GnuWin32, MinGW, etc.?  Can someone please provide step-by-step instructions on how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

1. install (https://sourceforge.net/downloads/mingw) and configure MinGW with packages g++ gcc libc6-dev libtool pkg-config
2. get gdb sources (I use 7.latest from https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) and put it into MinGW/msys/1.0 folder
3. run ./configure in msys shell (MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat)
4. run make and fix the following:
5. hypot compile error with help of this ['::hypot' has not been declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42276984/hypot-has-not-been-declared)
6. undefined constants for GetLastError function by adding `#include <winerror.h>` into `\gdb\gdbserver\win32-i386-low.c` `\gdb\gdbserver\win32-low.c` `gdb\ser-mingw.c`

I have checked build process using 7.11.1 and 7.12.1 sources

7.12.1 x32 is broken under windows
https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/issues/1909
https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/576/

Comment: You can look at my sourceforge wiki page to see how I build GDB under MSYS, see here: [gdbmingw / Wiki / Build GDB under MSYS](https://sourceforge.net/p/gdbmingw/wiki/Build%20GDB%20under%20MSYS/)